# Why `void* = 0` and `void* = nullptr` makes the difference?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, void-pointers, nullptr

I was playing with SFINAE and found behavior I cannot explain.

This [compiles fine](https://ideone.com/HDlWP7):

```
template<typename Integer,
         std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<Integer>::value>* = nullptr>
void foo(Integer) {}

template<typename Floating,
         std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<Floating>::value>* = nullptr>
void foo(Floating) {}
```

While this (`nullptr` replaced with `0`):

```
template<typename Integer,
         std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<Integer>::value>* = 0>
void foo(Integer) {}

template<typename Floating,
         std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<Floating>::value>* = 0>
void foo(Floating) {}
```

[gives me a compile error](https://ideone.com/pha2f9):

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: prog.cpp:13:10: error: no matching function for call to ‘foo(int)’
     foo(3);
          ^ prog.cpp:5:6: note: candidate: template<class Integer, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<_Tp>::value>* <anonymous> > void foo(Integer)  void foo(Integer) {}
      ^~~ prog.cpp:5:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed: prog.cpp:4:64: error: could not convert template argument ‘0’ to ‘std::enable_if_t<true, void>* {aka void*}’
          std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<Integer>::value>* = 0>
                                                                ^ prog.cpp:9:6: note: candidate: template<class Floating, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<_Tp>::value>* <anonymous> > void foo(Floating)  void foo(Floating) {}
      ^~~ prog.cpp:9:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed: prog.cpp:8:71: note: invalid template non-type parameter
          std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<Floating>::value>* = 0>
                                                                       ^
```

`enable_if_t` expands to `void` when there are no substitution failures, so I will have something like `void* = 0` among the list of template parameters. Why does it break compilation?..

Comment: Because `0` is an `int` and `nullptr` is a `void *`. You can probably cast that `0` to `(void *)` to make it work.

Comment: @tdk001: *"`nullptr` is a `void *`"*, wrong, it is a `std::nullptr_t`.

Comment: You can reduce the issue with `template<void* = 0>
void foo() {}`. clang give error *"null non-type template argument must be cast to template parameter type 'void *'"*. [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8255a4cbde425295)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Default template arguments follow their own conversion rules, which are stricter. Conversion of `0` to a pointer type in particular, is not applied.

See [[temp.arg.nontype]/5.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/temp.arg.nontype#5.2) (emphasis mine):

> for a non-type template-parameter of type pointer to object, qualification conversions ([conv.qual]) and the array-to-pointer conversion ([conv.array]) are applied; if the template-argument is of type `std::nullptr_t`, the null pointer conversion ([conv.ptr]) is applied.
>
> [ *Note:* In particular, neither the null pointer conversion for a zero-valued integral constant expression ([conv.ptr]) nor the derived-to-base conversion ([conv.ptr]) are applied. **Although `0` is a valid template-argument for a non-type template-parameter of integral type, it is not a valid template-argument for a non-type template-parameter of pointer type.** However, both `(int*)0` and `nullptr` are valid template-arguments for a non-type template-parameter of type “pointer to int.”  — end note ]

Comment: Good find. C++ has so many such non-obvious rules, It's frightening to think of all the ad hoc logic compiler writer must deal with.

Comment: I think the standard basically want to say "there are no templates in C, so at least *there* I don't have to be compliant with C" :)

Comment: what was the motivation behind this decision? prevent undesirable implicit conversions or something?

Comment: And note this is a rule that the most recent MSVC still does not enforce even with the standard set to latest.

Comment: @rustyx: some say that notes are not normative and cannot be used to prove anything. I had to edit/delete my answers couple of times because of this. So how to deal with such situations?

Comment: The note simply brings attention to the conversions which are not applied. It clarifies the rule just above.