# How do I use std::is_pod in a template argument?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, type-traits

I'm trying to get one set of behavior when something is a pod, and something else when it's not through template meta programming. I've written the below code, but I get a compilation error. I want to get:

```
yep
nope
```

but I get the following compiler error:

```
error C2993: 'std::is_pod<_Ty>': illegal type for non-type template parameter '__formal'
```

Using this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct A
{
    int b;
};

struct B
{
private:
    int b;
public:
    int c;
};

template <class Z, std::is_pod<Z>>
void x()
{
    std::cout << "yep" << std::endl;
}

template <class Z>
void x()
{
    std::cout << "nope" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    x<A>();
    x<B>();
    return 0;
}
```

Any advice?

Comment: You need a `bool` type template parameter in first place.

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? I thought I phrased the question clearly. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `std::enable_if` to use the value from `std::is_pod` in a SFINAE context.  That would look like

```
// only enable this template if Z is a pod type
template <class Z, std::enable_if_t<std::is_pod_v<Z>, bool> = true>
void x()
{
    std::cout << "yep" << std::endl;
}

// only enable this template if Z is not a pod type
template <class Z, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_pod_v<Z>, bool> = true>
void x()
{
    std::cout << "nope" << std::endl;
}
```

Do note that `std::is_pod` is deprecated in C++17 and has been removed from C++20.

Comment: Um, `template<class Z, void>` ... I don't think that works?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Yeah.  It's fixed now.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont It's working for me with both [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/D2207vPYoFAY4T0J) and [gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YllJH3VKvdDBSNPt) (sorry, I had the wrong code in the previous links)

Comment: @NathanOliver: I think that is from the reading of *"[Non-type template parameter] is one of the following types [..] a pointer type (to object or to function)"* which might exclude *pointer to void*. Another concern was allowed conversions which might not include the one required from `nullptr` to `void*`.

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm not sure.  It is one of the use cases shown [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) and I and others have used this technique for years.  Yakk himself has: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31524848/4342498

Comment: I used that too, but I think that pedantically, it was not allowed. maybe it is just `void* = nullptr`and not `void* = 0`. Notice that some examples use `int = 0`.

Comment: @NathanOliver *nod*, I've seen compilers refuse `void* =nullptr` or `void* =0`, and had to adapt to avoid it to be portable.  The error may have been something about `void` is not an object.  So I started using `enable_if_t< cond, bool> =true`.  I don't know *which* compiler.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Sounds good.  I think I'll change to that myself as I like how it looks.  I've updated the answer to use a `bool` instead of `void*`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Ya, it looks way better than it actually is, as the `=true` has nothing to do with truth.  ;)  But as a cargo cult pattern it works.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I know this is late but I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50765742/why-void-0-and-void-nullptr-makes-the-difference) today which at least explains why `void* =0` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

With c++17, you might use `if constexpr` (even if simple `if` is enough in your case as both branches are valid)

```
template <class Z>
void x()
{
    if constexpr (std::is_pod_v<Z>) {
        std::cout << "yep" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "nope" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
template <class Z,
  std::enable_if_t<std::is_pod<Z>{}, bool> =true
>
void x()
{
  std::cout << "yep" << std::endl;
}
```

this conditionally creates a non-type template parameter of type `bool`, and assigns it `true`.

If `is_pod<Z>{}` is false, it generates a SFINAE failure.

You'll have to implement the inverse condition in the other `x`.

An alternative is tag dispatching:

```
namespace impl {
  template <class Z>
  void x(std::true_type /* is pod */ )
  {
    std::cout << "yep" << std::endl;
  }

  template <class Z>
  void x(std::false_type /* is pod */ )
  {
    std::cout << "nope" << std::endl;
  }
}
template<class Z>
void x() {
  impl::x<Z>( std::is_pod<Z>{} );
}
```

where we use usual overload resolution to dispatch between the two bodies.  I, personally, find this the most sane.

Comment: This is going to cause an ambiguity with the second template.

Comment: @NathanOliver Note added.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use C++20, here's a solution that uses `requires`.

```
template <class Z>
requires std::is_standard_layout_v<Z> && std::is_trivial_v<Z>
void x()
{
    std::cout << "yep" << std::endl;
}
```